# How do I test 10 or more (dynamically changing the count) username and password in the login page?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to automate the login page if I have 1/10/more than 100 users?

1. Can we use the `HashMap`?
2. Can this also be done by data provider?

Comment: Yes, you can set the username and password in hashmap and iterate it

Answer (score 0):

you can try Keyword driven framework in which you can use Excel or CSV file to store the testdata and teststeps and can read that file from your code. 
you can TestNg for that.